# I am creating a java program but it is showing the error 'else' without 'if'

Tags: if-statement

```
class number
{
 public static void main(int a, int b, char c)
   { int r=0;
     if(c=='+')
     r= a+b;  
     System.out.println("result is "+ r);
    else if(c=='-')
     r= a-b; 
    System.out.println("result is "+ r);
    else if(c=='/')
    r= a/b;
    System.out.println("result is "+ r);
    else if(c=='%')
    r= a%b;
    System.out.println("result is "+ r);
    else if(c=='*')
    r= a*b;
    System.out.println("result is "+ r);
    else
    System.out.println("wrong operator");
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to your question is that you need braces around any multi-line statement within an if

```
if (c == '+') {
    r = a + b;
    System.out.println("result is " + r)
} else if (c == '-') {
    r = a - b;
    System.out.println("result is " + r);
}
```

There are other issues with your code:

Java strongly recommends that class names start with an upper case letter

```
class Number {
```

and your **main** has the wrong signature, it must be

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

you then need to get your a, b and c values from args[0], args[1] and args[2]. You will need to convert the String arguments.

Strongly suggest you work through a Java tutorial, which will explain all this in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can only write one statement within an "if" condition without braces. Since you have written 2 statements (i.e. the calculation and the printing) it will not compile.

In addition to that, the main method signature is incorrect as well and also make sure you use the Camel case naming convention while naming classes.

Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html for more details.

```
class Number { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        // get inputs for c, a and b
        int r=0; 
        if(c =='+'){ 
            r= a+b;
            System.out.println("result is "+ r); 
        }
        else if(c=='-') {
            r= a-b; 
            System.out.println("result is "+ r); 
        }
        else if(c=='/') {
            r= a/b; 
            System.out.println("result is "+ r); 
        }           
        else if(c=='%') {
            r= a%b; 
            System.out.println("result is "+ r);    
        }
        else if(c=='') {
            r= ab; 
            System.out.println("result is "+ r); 
        }
        else 
            System.out.println("wrong operator"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

See [this ref](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) :

```
   class number {
        public static void main(int a, int b, char c) {
            int r = 0;
            if (c == '+') {
                r = a + b;
            } else if (c == '-') {
                r = a - b;
            } else if (c == '/') {
                r = a / b;
            } else if (c == '%') {
                r = a % b;
            } else if (c == '') {
                r = ab;
            } else {
                System.out.println("wrong operator");
            }
    
            System.out.println("result is " + r); //This line is commonly used, so we put it here.
        }
    }
```